# Is there a rule (or house rule) for capping exploding dice damage in Earthdawn?

Tags: earthdawn-1e

So i've just hit a strange situation where an attack did 1d8 damage, and, thanks to the exploding mechanics, the wolf (worth 30 XP) did 33 Damage. That's 4 8's in a row and a 1.
It completely exploded the wizard, one shot, without even a chance to dodge or anything.

So i ruled with my players that i will only allow 2 rerolls MAXIMUM on a non aumented, non threaded weapon.

Is there a non house-rule for that effect somewhere?

For each forge weapon and thread, you add a max reroll (you need both for a reroll)
My reasonning is, with the step upgrade, you end up throwing more dices, so... that's just logical

Comment: That is why exploding dice are crazy, but the chance of it happening is extremely small, so the wizard did just have epic bad luck. I usually houserule just one reroll and if there is a second 8 the attack has some epic side effect - stunning, throwing the enemy 100ft backwards....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there's an official and optional (but strongly recommended) rule for that. Here's how it goes, with its source, of course:

> Limit the single-attack damage potential of non-magical weapons to a
>   maximum equal to three times the Damage step number of the weapon. The
>   Damage step of a weapon equals the character's Strength step plus the
>   weapon's Damage step. This optional rule does not affect the damage
>   potential of magical weapons—by definition, those weapons have very
>   few limits.

–p.116, [Earthdawn Companion](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/23995/Earthdawn-Companion-First-Edition) (1st ed.)

Btw, the *Rule of Three* is a semi-related, and also very important and useful optional rule detailed in the very same book. It's worth checking out if you don't know it yet. :)

Comment: oy! Many thanks for that. I'll go over both those rules again :)